# how do i call my variable so that it shows up on my react web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to call

```
var items = {
   

 Rice: [{ name: "Diri Djon Djon (Black rice)", Price: "$14.00" }],
  };
```

into one of my DIVS so that i can display the array of food items on this menu web page project that i am doing. Now i know that i am building an array and what i would like to do is display the menu items just like you would using a json file. Im not experienced in doing either as i am just starting with out with react and JavaScript. i know i must be forgetting something as i know i have done this before. i want to just call the data in var items or just items so that it will display the name of the dish and the price
Diri Djon Djon (Black rice) $14.00

My full code is down below and this is what i have is react

```
port default function Home(params) {
  var items = {
    Rice: [{ name: "Diri Djon Djon (Black rice)", Price: "$14.00" }],
  };
  return (
    <>
      {" "}
      <h1>Welcome to the best Hatian Resurant in the City!!</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente atque
        consequatur magnam ex repellat fuga officia corrupti quos distinctio,
        similique ad praesentium assumenda explicabo dolorum ea aperiam ab
        blanditiis voluptatum!
      </p>
      <hr />
      <div className="locate">
        
      </div>
      <div className="address-text">
        <h4></h4>
        <br />
        <div className="phone number">
          <h4></h4>
        </div>
        <div className="container2">
          <img className="image1" src="./images\HaitinFood.png" alt="food" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>Menue</h1>
        <h3>ENTRÉES </h3>
        <div className="container2">
          <p>Diri Djon Djon (Black rice) Medium $12 Large $14 </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>{items}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

i looked up how to call json files but i was told this way is faster and inline at least i think. Im not sure if i am explaining this correctly but this is the code above and the bottom is what i attempted and all it did was blank out the whole page.

The first image is what i have with my first attempt and the second image is when i remove the    `<div>{items}</div>`

[image: Empty React page]

[image: When i remove the div with the {text}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `items`variable is an object and React cannot render objects, what you need to do is extract the values of your object and create some JSX with it:

```js
<div>
  {items.Rice.map(rice => (
    <div className="container2">
      <p>{rice.name} {rice.price}</p>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```